# Touchpad not working and boot screen says 'Ubuntu Kylin' after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, upgrade, touchpad, kylin

tl;dr: I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. And now on boot up there's a wolf on the screen and says 'Ubuntu Kylin' and my touchpad doesn't work. How do I fix these issues?

I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 just an hour ago. I configured the update manager to show only LTS updates. Then I did "sudo apt-get install update-manager-core" followed by "sudo do-release-upgrade -d". It showed me that the updates are being pulled from 'trusty' version. When I restated after update I saw that boot screen is no longer saying 'Ubuntu' with those moving dots while booting, instead a wolf is there on the screen with text 'Ubuntu Kylin'.

Next, the desktop loads but my Touchpad is no longer working. I press 'Alt+ctrl+F6' but am unable to write anything because some messages are printing, like : "ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy"
"ieee80211 phy0: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4"

Then I notice that my Wi-Fi is also not working....Wait a second my Wi-Fi has stared working - i don't know how. But earlier the output for 'nm-tool' was showing state-unavailable and 'rfkill list" was showing both soft blocked and hard blocked as 'no'. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue has been fixed. Putting this answer here for visitors from the future.

To remove Ubuntu Kylin. I did following :

- Remove everything kylin

  sudo apt-get purge ubuntukylin-theme ubuntukylin*
- Change the default plymouth in alternatives

  sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
- To fix theme and icon pack

  sudo update-initramfs -u
- Remove grub background

  sudo update-grub
- In software center remove things that are related to Kylin from your system.

To fix touch pad:

Upon checking in the software updates I noticed that upon updating most of my software resources have been disabled. So, I enabled them. Then did following:

- Search for 'Synaptic' in the software center
- Click "show technical items" in the bottom
- Install everything that is related to touchpad, input or trusty (i.e. your Ubuntu version  name)

Hope that helps you dear visitor.